# How to handle an null response.json?

Tags: javascript, rest, discord.js, fetch-api

I'm currently trying to handle a NULL response to a REST API.

Code:

```
const { name } = await fetch(`api link`).then(response => response.json());
```

Now normally if there is an error I would simply use an `if(!name) return;`, but since the response is NULL and not an API response this won't work. I've been trying numerous things but none seem to work. I would appreciate some help on this or any solutions.

I am receiving an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when the response is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also response.json() return a promise. try with this:

```js
const response = await fetch(`api link`);
const result = await response.json();
if(result === null || result === undefined) {
 // return or do something
}

const { name } = result;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for